# Multiple log-in problem

Tags: asp.net

We have a web application with feature for logging in with  credientials 
The important requirement is once the user logs in he is not allowed to login from any other system or even another browser on same system 
 We used following solution which is mssql based : We have kept " Is_Loggedin" as a column with data type "bit" in a table. when a user logs in we set the flag  as "1" sowhen someone tries to log again ,the system is showing the error "The user is already logged in"
 When user logsout bit turns to "0"indicating user logged out. 
However this logic is failing in following scenarios

Problem scenario:
When user closes the browser the flag is "1"and user is locked in or situations when user gets system problem and unable to log out

Is there a better logic to handle this requirement?

Comment: Why do you have such a strange requirement in a web environment? IMO a web application must be able to handle this.

Comment: The requirement is probably to keep the system from being accessed by the same user multiple times at once.  The requirement is not all that strange IMO, but it is impossibly hard to reliably detect when a web user is in the system or when they have left.

Answer (score 0):

While the user is logged in, you could have a AJAX call that pings the server every 30 seconds that the user is logged in.  Have a column Is_LoggedIn, and Last_LoggedIn for the date/time when they last sent that AJAX call.  If it has been more than, say 1 minute, allow the user to login from another system.

You will also have a problem scenario if the user leaves their browser open for more than the session timeout period, usually 20 minutes.  Then they will get logged out on the next request, but not be able to login again because of that is_LoggedIn set to 1.  You would be better off doing some sort of time-based solution because keeping track of whether the user is still actively using a website is a very difficult problem because of the many ways they can leave the website without actually logging out.

If it is absolutely critical to avoid any chance of the user being logged in multiple places, you could also force all other places to logout automatically when the user logs into some new place.

Answer (score 0):

You can update 'Is_Loggedin' flag to 0 at session_end event of global.asax. 
session_end event is always call. session _end event call when session_timeout is expire.

Answer (score 0):

in the global.asax code behind I believe there is an even for session end. You could tie into that method and set the user's Is_LoggedIn flag to 0. You would then also need to tie a user to a session key to be able to track a user's session.

Edit:
Also, the use of a session cookie or a normal cookie may help if the user closes their browser. The cookie would authenticate them upon re-opening the browser window; however this has a potential security hole if the user is using a public computer.

Answer (score 0):

You could be to log the user out after sometime of inactivity (say 30 minutes). This way if the user closes the browser without logging out he will be able to log in again after 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Use Session_End as Pankaj suggest to make sure that the user's bit is set to 0 when logging out.

The issue with system failures is another problem. Maybe this could do the trick: When the user log in, the store the user's session ID in the database. When the user logs out, then clear the session ID. Every time the user makes a request you verify that the session ID matches the one stored in the database. If that is not the case, then invalidate the session, so that the user is logged out.

This should happen: If the user signs in, in another browser, the session ID would be updated. If user then goes back to the first browser windows and clicks on something, that session would be invalidated, and the user would be signed out automatically.